# Does it help concurrency if an sql table is split into multiple tables within the same database file?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, concurrency, sqlalchemy

I have a reasonably large SQL table in a single database file. This table is accessed by multiple independent processes. I am using sqlalchemy and python to access this table. One of these processes runs a fairly lengthy task on a subset of the table and only writes to a few specific fields. Occasionally I will run into concurrency issues with this setup.

So far I have been unable to reproduce the issue with minimal code. Which tells me that I am not understanding something here.

Example:

```
for x in session.query()
    do_something(x)
session.commit()
```

The entire loop could takes minutes to complete before the commit is issued.

It must have something to do with both processes trying to write to the same table at the same time.

I am considering splitting this table up into two tables.

Of course I could use a different database that has better concurrency support, but my code is not yet at a place where this is easily done.

**Q:** Does anybody here have experience with that approach and/or does it seem a worthwhile approach to reduce my concurrency issues?

Answer (score 0):

Database engines handle concurrency issues internally, which covers most applications use cases.

For instance, rows of a table can be locked from other processes until the current transaction is done; this is done in a fast enough time to not impact applications even with a fairly high number of transactions. It's always a good strategy to break down the task into smaller (perhaps singular) transactions, therefore locking the minimum number of rows possible.

Comment: I am not sure how SQLAlchemy handles that. My query might cover some 300 rows that then need to be processed. If SQLAlchemy loads all of them initially, then I can understand the concurrency issues. I also commit only after I processed all of them.

Comment: Commit every n number of transactions instead, experiment with n until you reach a number that won't hog your table, or simply commit every single transaction - the overhead is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficlt to tell without the code, but the first question that came to my mind is: why aren't you using locks? I imagine the big task looks a bit like this:

```
read something from table
do something with stuff read
write something to table
```

If so, you should only need to lock the table before writing and release the lock immediately after.

Comment: In pseudo code:
`
    for x in session.query(...):
        do_something(...)
    session.commit()
`
The entire loop could take a few minutes to run.

Comment: Lock right before session.commit() then, and release immediately after. This way the program doesn't slow down and you should avoid troubles with concurrency.

Comment: I would have thought that the commit execution is pretty quick. I was considering that the loop execution is to blame. (The session commit is supposed to be outside the loop. Not well visible with my messed up code example in the comment.)

Comment: @user3725459 you are defeating the purpose of a lock by locking **after** doing what the transaction is supposed to do, you might as well not lock at all.

Comment: @abstractpaper that's right, my fault. The suggestion to lock before any write operation (as small as possible) and release immediately after should still be useful though.

Comment: I will give locking a try. I wonder what will happen to the other process that is trying to write to the table at the same time.

Comment: The other process will spin lock until either the lock is removed or the process times out, whichever occurs first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using InnoDB, or MyISAM?  The former provides row locking functionality, while the latter only provides table locking.

That aside, read http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions, as that should cover all basic use cases.

Sounds like you also might want to look into SQLAlchemy's dogpile.cache integration.

Comment: I only use sqlalchemy. Thank you for the link and the dogpile.cache integration suggestion. Seems like I need to learn a lot more about this stuff